# How I can use openssl in Qt or CQA for symbian?

Tags: qt, symbian

I need to use some cryptography algorithms in my symbian Qt project.
But I could not compile QCA for my symbian environment.

1. How I can links my libcrypto.lib which is openssl static library for symbian to my QT application?I cannot find any place for configuring my QT application to accept this library.
2. Is it possible to compile QCA for symbian? If yes, how?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You can link against libcrypto.lib this way in your .pro file:

```
symbian: {
  LIBS += -llibcrypto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make code changes to QCA in order to make it compile for Symbian. So, while it is possible, you'll need to spend some time to make it work, it just won't work out of the box (as you've discovered).

Since you haven't specified exactly what it is that you need in terms of cryptographic functions, there is the QCryptographicHash class which provides MD4, MD5, and SHA1 hash generation.

Otherwise, you're stuck with openssl, which you can use laalto's answer for linking with libcrypto.lib